# Location of .ini for web applications

Tags: php, linux, ini

I have a php applicaiton and i'm planning to keep critical settings in a .ini file. However, i think that file can be accessed from over the web, so where is a "standard place" for it to be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it above the document/web root or specifically block access to it. For example, a common structure for PHP applications is:

```
application/
public/
```

Where `public` is the web root - so I usually store application configuration in `application/config` where I know it can't be accessed.

An alternative would be to block it using Apache:

```
<!-- Block access to all .ini files -->
<Files ~ "\.ini">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "standard place" is anywhere not affected by the directory root of the apache. For example you can place it under `/home/someuser/`, or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Place the .ini file outside the web root or protect it with .htaccess if you really want to keep it under the web root.

Answer (score 1):

It can be accessed if you place your INI file in your webroot/docroot.

Making sure the file is not accessible via the docroot is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database to be honest.

However, if you really want to use a flat file (e.g. .ini), you can place it in a directory, and use .htaccess to stop people from accessing it via their browser.  That way, you can still access the file via php file functions.

To do this, make a file called .htaccess in the folder you want to protect (e.g. ini/)

Then, in this file put:

```
deny from all
```

The folder is now not accessible by going to the url in the browser.

Comment: You can't store the database username/password/host in the database though can you. A config file is still useful for anything non-trivial with hard-coding reserved only for the throwaway stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Place the configuration in a directory that isn't readable by the webserver, yet *is* readable for the application. Generally, you have a specific directory that's readable by the webserver, such as "web", "www", "public" or "public_html". Make sure you put it in the directory below that one.

That way, your application can read the file:

```
$cfg = parse_ini_file( 
    realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../' ) . '/config.php' 
);
```

Your webserver doesn't know how to reach it though, so it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

a good example is Zend FW or any other php frameworks. directory structue is:

```
application/config/config.ini
library/Zend/
public/index.php
```

where public is accesible from web